# How to make a flat line in D3.js (version 3.x)

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I have a graph which I can add a flat line with the following:

```
  svg.append("line")          // attach a line
    .style("stroke", "black")
    .attr("x", 60)     // x position of the first end of the line
    .attr("y1", 60)      // y position of the first end of the line
    .attr("x2", 60)     // x position of the second end of the line
    .attr("y2", 60);
```

However, this only crosses 1/3 of the graph. How do I add a flat line that will always go as far as the graph is long? Thanks

[image]

Comment: how come the start coordinate and end coordinate are the same?  i mean: `x==x2`, `y1==y2` ?

Comment: `x` is not a valid attribute of `line`

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using scales, at least for your date axis, so I would do something like this:

```
// Scales
const xScale = d3.scaleTime()
  .range([0, 400])
  .domain(d3.extent(data, d => new Date(d.date)))
const yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
  .range([600, 0])
  .domain([0, 100])

svg.append("line")
  .style("stroke", "black")
  .attr('x1', 0)
  .attr('x2', 400)
  .attr('y1', yScale(60))
  .attr('y2', yScale(60))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add line to complete graph by using range function that you generated for making line chart.

```
line_straight = svg.append("line")          // attach a line
                  .style("stroke", "black")
                  .attr("x", 0)     // x position of the first end of the line
                  .attr("y1", yScale(0.8))      // y position of the first end of the line
                  .attr("x2", xScale(n-1))     // x position of the second end of the line
                  .attr("y2", yScale(0.8));
```

Below i am attaching my code. Here is the jsfiddle to the code. https://jsfiddle.net/nmks14ub/1/

```js
// 2. Use the margin convention practice 
var margin = {top: 50, right: 50, bottom: 50, left: 50}
  , width = window.innerWidth - margin.left - margin.right // Use the window's width 
  , height = window.innerHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom; // Use the window's height

// The number of datapoints
var n = 21;

// 5. X scale will use the index of our data
var xScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, n-1]) // input
    .range([0, width]); // output

// 6. Y scale will use the randomly generate number 
var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1]) // input 
    .range([height, 0]); // output 

// 7. d3's line generator
var line = d3.line()
    .x(function(d, i) { return xScale(i); }) // set the x values for the line generator
    .y(function(d) { return yScale(d.y); }) // set the y values for the line generator 
    .curve(d3.curveLinear) // apply smoothing to the line

// 8. An array of objects of length N. Each object has key -> value pair, the key being "y" and the value is a random number


var dataset = d3.range(n).map(function(d) { return {"y": d3.randomUniform(1)() } })

// 1. Add the SVG to the page and employ #2
var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

// 3. Call the x axis in a group tag
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisBottom

line_straight = svg.append("line")          // attach a line
                  .style("stroke", "black")
                  .attr("x", 0)     // x position of the first end of the line
                  .attr("y1", yScale(0.8))      // y position of the first end of the line
                  .attr("x2", xScale(n-1))     // x position of the second end of the line
                  .attr("y2", yScale(0.8));
                  
// 4. Call the y axis in a group tag
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(d3.axisLeft(yScale)); // Create an axis component with d3.axisLeft

// 9. Append the path, bind the data, and call the line generator 
svg.append("path")
    .datum(dataset) // 10. Binds data to the line 
    .attr("class", "line") // Assign a class for styling 
    .attr("d", line); // 11. Calls the line generator
```

```css
.line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: #ffab00;
    stroke-width: 3;
}
  
.overlay {
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

/* Style the dots by assigning a fill and stroke */
.dot {
    fill: #ffab00;
    stroke: #fff;
}
  
  .focus circle {
  fill: none;
  stroke: steelblue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<body>
</body>

<!-- Load in the d3 library -->
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```